# DataMapper With ruby sinatra Many to many :trough => Reasource

Tags: sql, ruby, database, sinatra, datamapper

I am trying to create a new user group many to many relation.
I am using these dataMapper Objects

```
module Core_authentication

  class User
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :username, String
    property :password, BCryptHash
    property :email, String
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

    #Creating join tables to link to group and person information
    has n, :Person, :through => Resource
    has n, :Group, :through => Resource
  end  

  class Group
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :name, String

    #Another jointable link group to link to functions and classification levels
    has n, :Function, :through => Resource
    has n, :Classificationlevel, :through => Resource
  end  

  class Person
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :firstname, String
    property :lastname, String
    property :adress, String
    property :postcode, String
    property :telefoon, String
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

  end  

  class Function
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :name, String

  end  

  class Classificationlevel
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :levelcode, String
    property :name, String

  end

end
```

and these code to create and fill the tables

```
user = Core_authentication::User.create
user.username = params['username']
user.password = params['password']
user.email = params['email']
#user.save

group = Core_authentication::Group.first_or_create(:name => params['group'])
group.name = params['group']
group.save

user.Group << group
```

But when i want try it gives me this error

```
NoMethodError at /register
undefined method `group' for #<Core_authentication::User:0x007f96cc2bf920>

    file: App.rb
    location: block in <class:App>
    line: 46
```

So it fails on the point where i need to join the tables into a table with both ids.
Why does it do this and wat is a possible solution?
Is that i placed the DataMapper object in a module the problem?

Comment: Aren't the `has n` arguments supposed to be plural? E.g. `has n, :person*s*, :through => resource*s*`. Also, where are the `belongs_to` decorations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem after lots of try's 
It was Fixed by using  `has n, :model, through => Resource` and placing it at both model classes.

This wil create a join table containing both resource ids here a small example.

```
module Core_authentication

  class User
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :username, String, :required => true, :unique => true  
    property :password, BCryptHash, :required => true 
    property :email, String, :format => :email_address, :required => true
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

    #Creating join tables to link to group and person information
    has n, :persons, :through => Resource

  end 

  class Person
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :firstname, String
    property :lastname, String, :required => true
    property :adress, String
    property :postcode, String, :length => 6, :required => true
    property :telefoon, String
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

    has n, :users, :through => Resource

  end
```

Then just create the 2 objects then link the objects by

```
user.persons << person
```

and then save